# Is there another equivalence relation on based maps between spheres which form the same graded ring as the homotopy groups?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on continuous based maps from $S^k$ to $S^n$, where $k$ and $n$ range over the positive integers.

Suppose that

1. Given maps $f, f^\prime: S^k \to S^n$ and $g, g^\prime: S^n \to S^m$, if $f \sim f^\prime$ and $g \sim g^\prime$, then we have an equivalence $g\circ f \sim g^\prime \circ f^\prime : S^k \to S^m$ of composite maps.
2. Given continuous maps $f,f^\prime, g,g^\prime: S^k \to S^n$, if $f \sim f^\prime$ and $g \sim g^\prime$, then we have an equivalence $g\vee f \sim g^\prime \vee f^\prime: S^k \to S^n$ of maps obtained by pinching the sphere $S^k$ along its equator.
3. Using the multiplication induced on the set ${\mathrm{Map}}_*(S^k, S^n)$ by the operation $\vee$ given in item 2, the group ${\mathrm{Map}}_*(S^k, S^n)/\sim$ of equivalence classes is isomorphism to $\pi_k(S^n)$.
4. Given continuous maps $f : S ^{m + j} \to S^m$ and $g : S^{n + k} \to S^n$, if $m$ and $n$ are sufficiently large (in the stable range, cf item 3), then we have an equivalence $f \wedge g \sim  g \wedge f: S^{m+n+j+k}\to S^{m+n}$ of smash products.

It is necessary that $\sim$ is the homotopy equivalence?

Comment: For 3 you need an extra property of $\sim$ that turns $\mathrm{Map_*}(S^k,S^n)/\mathord{\sim}$ into a group (homotopy is needed to define $\pi_k(S^n)$). Once you have that, I would guess that with the axiom of choice, you can produce such a relation. Maybe you should demand that $\sim$ is compatible with some topology on $\mathrm{Map_*}(S^k,S^n)$, if you want to exclude pathological behaviour.

Comment: Yes, Sebestian, you are right that I need $\sim$ to be compatible with the operation $\vee$ in order that $\mathrm{Map}(S^k, S^n)/\sim $ forms a magma.

Comment: I'm actually hoping to see what kinds of pathological behavior can occur, and whether the isomorphisms with the usual homotopy groups of sphere are enough to constrain the relation $\sim$.